# how to add constraint in Pulp BinPacking such that two items are not assigned in same bag

Tags: constraint-programming, pulp

I'm using this code and want to add a constraint such that say item a and b are not assigned in the same bag

Comment: https://github.com/mbasilyan/binpacking/blob/master/binpacker.py?lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_pulse_read%3BVqIyMFQWR9epdBxSRfrU%2BA%3D%3D

Answer (score 3):

Let

```
x(i,j) = 1 if item i is placed in bin j
         0 otherwise
```

Then

```
x(a,j) + x(b,j) <= 1 for all j
```

will prevent a and b to be placed in the same bin.

Comment: prob += lpSum([x["bread", i] + x["squash", i] for i in range(maxBins)]) < 1, ("Item Constraints -- " + str(j[0]))
This is what i added. Doesn't work

Comment: Indeed. That is something very different than what I suggested, So it should not work.

Comment: prob += lpSum([x["bread", i] + x["squash", i] for i in range(maxBins)]) <=1, ("Item Constraints -- " + str(j[0]))
I did apply a "<=" as you suggested just accidentally posted wrong
Is there any thing else that I should change?